# How to set background color for div in ASP.NET web page

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to design a web form in ASP.NET. In that I am trying to set a background color to different ***empty divs***. Normally a simple html code like below works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
         #header{
             width:100%;
             height:20%;
             background-color:lightblue
         }
         #nav-bar{
             width:100%;
             height:5%;
             background-color:lightgreen;
         }
         body,html{
             margin:0;
         }
      </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="nav-bar">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I use this same snippet in ASP.NET, I fail to achieve the desired result. The browser displays nothing. My aspx code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head runat="server"><title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header {
                background-color: lightblue;
                height: 20%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #nav-bar {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                height: 5%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            body, html { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body runat="server">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div id="nav-bar">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So how can I set a background color to an empty div in ASP.NET? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In CSS, you normally target element types or classes, not particular ID's. ID's in ASP.NET you need to be careful, as certain situations can cause the ID to be different on the client than it is on the server. What happens if you switch to using classes?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the above code. There must be something else wrong here. What happens if you put something into the div? i.e. force it to take up some space instead of releying on CSS to do this

Comment: Your body doesn't have a height, so your `div`s wont either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `#header`and `#nav-bar`have percentage heights. You'll see if you change them to `px`dimensions, they empty div's still show up. So your problem doesn't have anything with ASP.NET it's just a CSS issue.

If you want the heights to be responsive to the user's screen, you should try the `vh`tag. This stands for `viewport height`. So if you have `20vh`for example, it will take up 20% of the users screen height.

See my updated JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0mr9z6hy/2/

Comment: No problem buddy! @Dendi_Nim

Answer (score 0):

percentage heights may work differently across browsers

but one problem is you have no height specified on the body so the height is only really the height of the actual content of your page which is not much.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```